# Exporting Silverlight animation

Tags: c#, silverlight, video

I have a silverlight animation, is it possible to have a button that once clicked will start the animation and once finished export it to wmv?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 97% sure this isn't possible in Silverlight.  Silverlight is sandboxed for security so you don't have full access to the client machine.  This means that creating a WMV recording of an animation would be impossible.

Even if you were using WPF which would have direct access to the client machine this would be difficult or impossible.

Why don't you give some more details on what you are trying to accomplish and maybe we can give a better answer.